Does JSON Schema Validation support custom error messages?
I'm using JSON Schema to validate a json object like below:
{
     "json": 
           { "is_expanded_identification": false, "identity":
                                                  { "concat_id": 44446543R, "concat_id_type_code": 1 } 
           }
        ,
     "study_year": "2025"      
}

Here is my Json Schema:
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "json",
    "study_year"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "json": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "is_expanded_identification",
        "identity"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "is_expanded_identification": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "identity": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "concat_id",
            "concat_id_type_code"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "concat_id": {
              "type": "integer",
                 "errorMessage": {
                      "type": "My custom messsage"
                                 }
            },
            "concat_id_type_code": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "study_year": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^\\d{4}$"
    }
  }
}


I would expect it to show my custom message because of the "contact_id" field R letter,
Instead it show the JSchema default message "Unexpected character encountered while parsing number: R.".
I'v tried "errorMessage"/'message" but none of them worked for me.
Isn't it support with Json SChema Validations of newtosoft?

JSON Schema itself (the specification) does not prescribe error messages, so it's up to tooling to decide how to support them.
I'm unsure about Newtonsoft, but my lib JsonSchema.Net does (based on System.Text.Json, docs).
